# Why are .goutputstream-xxxxx files created in home folder? 

Tags: gnome

I find a lot of files with names of the like

```
.goutputstream-xxxxx
```

where xxxxx are some alphanumeric characters.

Here is a screenshot of the home folder

[image: screenshot of home folder]

Any idea why I should keep these or can I remove and also stop further creation?

Comment: This bug has been fixed https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/984785

Comment: Those are POSIX process forking tunnels, that had not been closed properly. We can produce them from php  `posix_mkfifo()` and `pcntl_exec()`

Comment: Problem appears again in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: One suddenly appeared at `~/Desktop` in ubuntu 23.04 once SIGTERM was passed to gnome-shell. The `stat` shows that it had been created 3 days before though, but it wasn't visible. Also the `file` output: `.goutputstream-X8R6C2: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract, compression method=[0x305c]`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is a bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/984785

Pretty sure it's not ubuntu one - I don't have it here and have the files.

I delete them every now and again, not caused me any issues.

You can run this command in a terminal to delete them all:

```
cd && rm .goutputstream-* -v
```

Comment: I believe, those files are related with gstreamer or pulseaudio.

Answer (score 7):

These are temporary files that should have been deleted. Most likely created by Ubuntu One.

This issue has been discussed to detail on this forum:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11953534

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS The first sentence of this answer really does fundamentally answer the question (or attempt to, I'm not saying this is right). And it is the essential information from the linked thread. I'm not sure this particular answer actually does require any additional details.

Comment: I do not use Ubuntu One and still get these files.

Answer (score 5):

A fix is still in the works (via the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/984785/comments/102)):

> upstream commited a fix to git if somebody wants to try the change:
>   http://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/commit/?id=afdb2abb13896a3d5caecabd2f7158e8047f9956

For now, I'm running this in cron (`myuser` is my username, and using `crontab -e` to edit ) :

`@daily  find /home/myuser/.goutputstream-* -mtime +2 -print | xargs rm -f`

Comment: Would I just add the above cron job into a crontab exactly as you have written it?  If so, where do I save it when prompted by nano?

Comment: If you use `crontab -e`, the default location should be correctly selected already.

Comment: Just use `-delete` instead of your `xargs`, it is safer and simpler.

Comment: @queueoverflow  I assume that works as long as you're using GNU find.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is because of a kernel update, or what have you but I was able to accomplish the same result as:

```
cd && rm .goutputstream-* -v
```

by running:

```
rm .goutputstream-*
```

Comment: The former goes to the **home directory** `cd`, deletes all `.goutputstream-*` files and gives you a list of the files deleted. The latter deletes all `.goutputstream-*` files in the **current directory**. So your solution won't work if the user isn't already in the home directory.

Comment: Well, it will work, it just won't delete the `.goutputstream-*` files that may be in the home directory. If there had been any such files in that current directory, they would have been deleted.

Comment: Nothing to do with any kernel.